# Setting up Anaconda for VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am trying to set up Python Anaconda for Visual Studio Code, I can set the interpreter to run as python however when I run it I get an error message saying: "The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid.", when I open the launch.json I get the following output:

```
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
```

I am not entirely sure what I should change here to make it work?

Any ideas are very welcome as I am not able to find anything on this on google

Edit: This is how my editor looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8kY8.jpg

Comment: _I can set the interpreter to run as python_ Can you be more specific? Did you follow the official instructions for [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) ?

Comment: Yeah I did and as far as I can see it shows up as correct: https://imgur.com/a/xoFmxc6 (I am on Windows by the way)

Comment: can you activate conda env using command prompt ? Goto start and search for command prompt. Open it up and type in `conda activate base` . What is the result ?

Comment: Not entirely sure how I would do that?

Comment: If the conda environment cannot be activated then you have to set PATH variable for conda.

Comment: Just to level with you I have no idea how I do that either, I literally started with this and am not able to find anyone else having the same problem as me. Would you be able to provide me some more information?

Comment: @nonein They were likely referring to CMD, or the Anaconda prompt. Basically, can you use Conda from the command line?